# String format in C %*s

Tags: c, string, input, printf, conversion-specifier

I saw somewhere a portion of code in C

```
char name[51];
int group = 0;
scanf("%*s %50s %*s %d", name, &group);
printf("%s / %d\n", name, group);
```

If we introduce

> "Name:Smith Group:7"

it waits for us to introduce another values. It's strange. What is exactly happening and what does `%*s %50s %*s` mean. I saw `%*s` before but never put before and after reading a string.

Comment: Yeah I figured it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The `*` after the `%` and before the conversion specifier is an assignment suppression flag. It indicates that the matched entry will not be stored (.i.e., will be discarded) and a corresponding storage argument is not needed.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.2

> *[...] Unless assignment suppression was indicated by a `*`, the
>   result of the conversion is placed in the object pointed to by the first argument following
>   the format argument that has not already received a conversion result.*

That said, for the input

```
Name:Smith Group:7
```

what you expect is something like

- `%*s` matches "Name:" and discards
- `%50s` matches "Smith" and stores
- `%*s` matches "Group:" and discards
- `%d` matches `7` and stores.

However, there is a problem. For the conversion specifier `s`,

> *Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters*

That means, it'll scan and match until a whitespace, and since there's no whitespace till before "Group", the whole "Name:Smith" will be consumed by the first `%*s` directive. Same happens for the following `%*s`, also. Thus, the conversion specification does not conclude, and `scanf()` waits for the next input to be consumed.

So, to match the conversion specification, supply the input as

```
Name: Smith Group: 7
     ^^           ^^
```